# Debugging information not included with -g

Tags: debugging, gcc, gdb, nasm, kdbg

Currently attempting to debug with KDbg / gdb the source code for Towers of Hanoi from http://www.kernelthread.com/projects/hanoi//html/asm.html (great resource)

Since I wanted to review how the stack is used within this problem, I assembled it with NASM and used GCC to link it. However, I noticed that in KDbg, the current point of execution was not updating (i.e, I could not tell where I was within the file). Since KDbg relies on gdb, I ran the code within gdb to see if I experienced similar issues.

If I set a breakpoint on line #30 in the program (which is a line within the main function), I get the following:

```
(gdb) break 30
Breakpoint 2 at 0x804840b: file hanoi.asm, line 30.
(gdb) next
Single stepping until exit from function main,
which has no line number information.
```

I'm currently compiling the assembly with the following little script I've written (I should probably migrate to a make file, but this has been working up until now)

```
bschlinker@net1develop02:~/.scripts$ cat asmgcc
# /usr/bin/sh

nasm -f elf -g -F stabs $1.asm -l $1.lst
gcc -g $1.o -o $1
```

I just migrated from CentOS to Ubuntu, so I'm not sure if this is an OS environment issue I'm not familiar with, or another issue.

As always, thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: @Paul R -- Unfortunately, I tried making that change already (gcc -g $1.o -o $1). Doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `-F dwarf` instead of `-F stabs`.

Comment: Yep -- it worked. Care to explain why kdbg on Ubuntu no longer likes stabs, while CentOS kdbg still does?

Comment: I don't know. I do know that STABS is really old (and quite horrible) debug format, and you should generally stay away from it if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can assemble with `as -o tmp.o something.s && ld -s -o something tmp.o && rm tmp.o`.
In gdb just `display/8i *$eip` (or *rip* if 64 bit), it will display 8 instructions after instruction pointer with every step. So you don't need debugging info at all ;-)